# What is the difference between using constructor vs state = {} in React / React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have seen both

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      loggedIn: false,
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    loggedIn: false,
  }
}
```

What are the use cases for both? Are there advantages / disadvantages? Is one a better practice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Use constructor when you want to save `props` data into `state`**

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: props.loading,
      loggedIn: props.loggedIn,
    }
  }
}
```

**Otherwise you can directly set the `state` for hard coded data**

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    loggedIn: false,
  }
}
```

Comment: Copying props into state is considered an anti pattern by the official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: @Remi Please read this para `Only use this pattern if you intentionally want to ignore prop updates.`, you can store props to state for default or initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The performance is same in both the cases so it's just a matter of personal preference. Defining state outside of class happens to be a newer implementation than defining it inside a constructor so I would suggest you use explicit state definition.